# Redirecting all requests from a certain domain to another in Android (like a host file)

Tags: android, android-networking

I'm looking to port something from Windows to Android, which requires a host files modification. Is there any equivalent functionality that will allow me to redirect http requests from a certain domain to another IP just within my app. Is this possible?